# The requested URL /TP_MVC/test.php was not found on this server?

Tags: php

i am trying to send data from a form in html ,the 2 files(index.html and test.php) exist on same directory TP_MVC ,my code is very simple :

```html
<form action=\"test.php\" method=\"post\">
ID:<br>
  <input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" >
  <br>
Name:<br>
  <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" >
  <br>

Date of Birth:<br>
  <input type=\"text\" name=\"date\" >
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">
</form>
```

```html
//
<?php

echo $_POST['id'];
echo $_POST['name'];
echo $_POST['date'];



?>
```

and i got this message when i run the exemple:
Not Found
The requested URL /TP_MVC/test.php was not found on this server.
i am using wampserver 2.5 please help me.

Comment: Well, how should we now what `TP_MVC` is without you telling us? How should we know if such thing exists on your system? How should we know if some resource `test.php` is published by your system?

Comment: That was no reply. It was a comment. I tried to point out what is missing in your question so that you can `edit` your question and add those details.

Comment: TP_MVC is the folder where test.php exist
i said too that i am using wampserver 2.5 everything is cool with data base connections and many other tests but when i try to use post and get methods this problem occurs

Comment: I think what @arkascha was trying to say is that, there is NO way that file will be in the **same** directory as your html form, that it will return a 404 error. I strongly suggest you edit your question and name the files accordingly.

Comment: hello @SamuelAsor the 2 files index and test.php which will receive data are in the same directory